# Pine script negative for loop

Tags: pine-script

Why is this label printed? Maybe I don't fully understand how pine script loops works. Does it go backwards as well?

```
indicator("lab", overlay = true)

for i = 0 to -1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(i))

plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

From https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Loops.html

> The expression in `by <expression>` is optional. It is the step by which the loop counter is increased **or decreased** on each iteration of the loop. Its default value is 1 when start `value < end value`. **It is -1 when start `value > end value`**. The step (+1 or -1) used as the default is determined by the start and end values.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to force a loop to be positive?

Comment: apparently, just set the `by` expression to what you want to increment by, and that should do